# Keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure

Tags: gpg

This error has arise when I add tor to my repository and try to use this command:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
```

It's shows this error
`gpg: keyserver receive failed: Server indicated a failure`

Comment: Welcome maybe [this is the answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/16447/22377).